# Automatically scroll on the table using link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I automatically scroll or focus on the table upon redirect using the class name when the button is clicked I used a link_to enclosed inside is a div

```
 <%= link_to employees_path do %>
   <div>......
   </div>
 <% end %>

<tbody>
 <% @request.each do |s| %>
 <tr data-expanded="true">
     <td><%= s.date.strftime('%B %Y') %></td>
     <td><%= s.name %></td>
     <td><%= s.created_at %></td>
     <td><%= s.updated_at %></td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried using but it doesnt work on the table

```
 autofocus: true
```

and I also tried to mimic it going to the bottom of the page

```
<script>
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: document.body.scrollHeight},"fast");
</script>
```

What I want is when the user clicks the button the user will be automatically scrolled to the table or focused on table, but only when the button is clicked will it be focused.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Where is the table? Do you mean to have one input autofocused upon page loading?

Comment: sorry edited and included the table I want is when the user clicks the button the user will be scrolled to the table, but only when the button is clicked will it be focused.

Comment: @john i have given a solution, please have a look on it.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div id="scroll-to-table"> 
    <%= link_to employees_path do %>
       <div>......
       </div>
     <% end %>
   </div>


<div id="scroll_to_table">
  <tbody>
   <% @request.each do |s| %>
   <tr data-expanded="true">
       <td><%= s.date.strftime('%B %Y') %></td>
       <td><%= s.name %></td>
       <td><%= s.created_at %></td>
       <td><%= s.updated_at %></td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#scroll-to-table").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scroll_to_table").offset().top},
        'slow');
  });

</script>
```

Comment: it does not work when i click the button and let me just add the table and the button are on separate pages

Comment: hmm, i did't get you.

Comment: sorry it didn't work when I tried it. Correct me if I am wrong I think the solution you gave is for a single view?  Let me explain the link_to is on a different view when I click the button it redirects to another view which contains the table. Two separate views

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by adding an anchor

```
<%= link_to employees_path(anchor: "value") do %>

<a name = "value"></a>
```

Comment: did my answer helped you?